# Variation of a locked key

Tags: probability

A code to open a box are in 6 different numbers from 1 to 30.
And the numbers in the code should be increasing order. 
How many ways can I make the code?

If there is not the condition, increasing order, I can answer $$30*29*28*27*26*25$$

But how should I treat the increasing order?

Comment: Hint: if the code had only two numbers and no constraint, you would compute $(30+30+\ldots+30) = 30 \cdot 29$. Adding your constraint, this becomes $(29+28+27+\ldots+2+1) = 30 \cdot 15$.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand it.  Especially, the third line.  Please give me more pint.

Comment: More "pint"? Need a beer or a "hint" (just kidding).

Comment: When you choose (say) $a_1 = 12$ and $a_2 > a_1$, you must choose $a_2$ between 13 and 30 (a total of 18 cases). In general, if you pick $a_1$ as your first number, you have only $30-a_1$ choices for the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531231/find-all-permutations-in-increasing-order) covers your question. Essentially, since there should only be one way each set of $6$ numbers can be arranged in order, the problem reduces from finding the permutations $^{30}P_6$ to finding the combinations $^{30}C_6$